# Email without body being sent to newly added users

Tags: 7, users, emails

In "admin>config>people>account-settings" for "Who can register accounts?" settings I have selected:

- Visitors, but administrator approval is required.
- Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account.

I have even enabled notifications for sending emails to newly added users from the options available at the bottom of the same page and I am using the default subject and body for the mail.

I have got an very unusual problem that my newly added user receives a mail from my site without any body. Though the subject of the mail is same but the body of the mail doesn't shows up; all I can see in email's body are just three dots (...). Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any module that alters mail before being sent? If so, can you check if they are causing the problem.

Can you check for other mails as well, sent by Drupal. Do they generate the same issue?

Apart from that, please check the mail headers once, that might give you some hint.

If you get anything, Post it here, I will be happy to help ....

Comment: I am using contact module and it is working fine. As far as I know contact module doesn't alter any functioning of these 'user profile' related mails. I would like to add one more problem here, In fact my admin(super-user) ID is receiving all emails except the emails related to user profiles. i.e; whenever I create a new user, my site ID doesn't get any new email regarding this issue. I hope that's what u were asking for